# Second time click of a button inside updatePanel, the event does not fire in jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, autopostback

In my aspx file, I have:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" UpdateMode="Always" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In my JavaScript file I have:

```
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Button1').click(function (e) {
        alert('hello');
    });
```

But only the first time click on the button, I got `alert('hello')`, and no more alert messages afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For dynamic content, use jQuery's [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method.

```
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Button1').live('click', function (e) {
    alert('hello');
});
```

Also, I'd recommend using a class instead of the ID. Using the ID is fragile to any code changes which affect the ASP.NET container/control structure:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" class="performsMyClickAction" />

$('.performsMyClickAction').live('click', function (e) { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you because I am using several divs with the same class css and I need to do some events for a certain div therefore I am calling the div using its ID. Thanks for your advise as well!

Comment: Instead of overusing the `class` attribute in WebForms projects I use the End-Of selector to only account for the ending of the ID. In this case the selector would be: `$('input[id$=Button1]').live()`, where the dollar-equals combination matches the End-Of of the attribute `id`. This way it will disregard the annoying long prefix.

Comment: I get an error with that and shows the following error: `0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method`. My question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431269/why-a-button-inside-an-updatepanel-doesnt-execute-a-jquery-event-after-the-firs

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering why you have your selector as #ct_100_ContenPlaceHolder1_Button1.  I switched it to #Button1 and it appeared to work fine for me.

Comment: Because you did not place it inside of a PLaceHolder. It works fine for the first time, but second time, it did not fire :(

Answer (score 0):

When the `UpdatePanel` does its asynchronous callback, you lose your jquery event registration, because the contents of the panel get completely replaced.

You can execute more JavaScript to re-wire things up by adding a script registration to the script manager during your callback. Something like this should get you close (in your button's server-side click handler):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
    this,
    GetType(),
    "AnyStringYouWant",
    "$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Button1').click(function (e) {alert('hello');});",
    true);
```

Comment: it sounds interesting!

Could you please let me know where should I place it?

Comment: It looks like you have your answer already, but in response to your comment, you could use this code in your code-behind, probably anywhere before the Render stage of the page lifecycle. OnLoad should be fine.

Comment: Yes, that works fine as well but I prefer to use 'live' as the answer above in jQuery. It works super!

Thanks!

Comment: How would I solve it in my case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431269/why-a-button-inside-an-updatepanel-doesnt-execute-a-jquery-event-after-the-firs