# Why a button inside an UpdatePanel doesn't execute a JQuery event after the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a button (inside an `UpdatePanel`) which opens a popup form which allows me to enter some data then submitting does some function (Updates an UpdatePanel with the new data entered) and closes the pop-up:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlCreateMsg" runat="server" NavigateUrl="JavaScript:void(0);" CssClass="linkOff" ClientIDMode="Static">Create New</asp:HyperLink>

<div id="popupContact">
    <a id="popupContactClose" title="Close Window">x</a>
    <h3>Add a New Message</h3>
    <div id="dvFirst" class="mainSecond">
        <div id="leftdiv3" class="leftdiv">Client: </div>
        <div id="rightdiv3" class="rightdiv"><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCliNewMsg" AutoPostBack="false" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="chosen-select" ></asp:DropDownList></div>
    </div>
    <div id="dvSecond" class="mainSecond">
        <div id="leftdiv4" class="leftdiv">Site: </div>
        <div id="rightdiv4" class="rightdiv"><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSitNewMsg" AutoPostBack="false" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="chosen-select"></asp:DropDownList></div>
    </div>
   <div id="dvThird" class="mainSecond">
        <div id="leftdiv5" class="leftdiv">Provider: </div>
        <div id="rightdiv5" class="rightdiv"><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProNewMsg" AutoPostBack="false" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="chosen-select"></asp:DropDownList></div>
    </div>
    <div id="dvFourth" class="mainFirst">
        <div id="leftdiv1" class="leftdivspec"><sup style="color: #FF0000; font-weight: bold;">*</sup>Message: </div>
        <div id="rightdiv1" class="rightdivspec"><asp:TextBox ID="tbMessage" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="30" Rows="5"></asp:TextBox></div>
    </div>
    <div id="dvFifth" class="mainSecond">
        <div id="leftdiv2" class="leftdiv">Active?</div>
        <div id="rightdiv2" class="rightdiv"><asp:CheckBox ID="cbIsActive" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" /></div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 96%; text-align: right; padding: 2%;">
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upSubmit" ClientIDMode="Static" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="btnExport" ClientIDMode="Static" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="SubmitAdminMessage" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="backgroundPopup"></div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
//CONTROLLING EVENTS IN jQuery
$(document).ready(function () {

    //LOADING POPUP
    //Click the button event!
    $("#hlCreateMsg").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //centering with css
        centerPopup();
        //load popup
        loadPopup();
    });
    $("#Create").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //centering with css
        centerPopup();
        //load popup
        loadPopup();
    });
    $("#btnSubmit").on('click', function (e) {
        alert('test');
        e.preventDefault();

        disablePopup();
    });

    //CLOSING POPUP
    //Click the x event!
    $("#popupContactClose").click(function () {
        disablePopup();
    });
    //Click out event!
    $("#backgroundPopup").click(function () {
        disablePopup();
    });
    //Press Escape event!
    $(document).keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27 && popupStatus == 1) {
            disablePopup();
        }
    });
});


//SETTING UP OUR POPUP
//0 means disabled; 1 means enabled;
var popupStatus = 0;

//loading popup with jQuery magic!
function loadPopup() {
    //loads popup only if it is disabled
    if (popupStatus == 0) {
        $("#backgroundPopup").css({
            "opacity": "0.7"
        });
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#popupContact").fadeIn("slow");
        popupStatus = 1;
    }
}

//disabling popup with jQuery magic!
function disablePopup() {
    //disables popup only if it is enabled
    if (popupStatus == 1) {
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#popupContact").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#tbMessage").val('');
        $("#cbIsActive").attr("checked", false);
        popupStatus = 0;
    }
}

//centering popup
function centerPopup() {
    //request data for centering
    var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var popupHeight = $("#popupContact").height();
    var popupWidth = $("#popupContact").width();
    //centering
    $("#popupContact").css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": windowHeight / 2 - popupHeight / 2,
        "left": windowWidth / 2 - popupWidth / 2
    });
    //only need force for IE6

    $("#backgroundPopup").css({
        "height": windowHeight
    });
}
```

So the first time the page load and I click on the `hlCreateMsg` link, the pop-up comes up and I am able to enter the data and submit. The pop-up closes and updates the `UpdatePanel` also displays the `test` alert window. But each consequent time I open the pop-up (without refreshing the page), the submit button does update the `UpdatePanel` but it doesn't close the pop-up nor does it display the `test` alert.

How do I resolve the issue?

UPDATE: After looking through some other questions it was solved by modifying the code to this:

```
$("#btnSubmit").live('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        disablePopup();
    });
```

But that gives me an error: `0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method`

Comment: The `.live()` API is long-deprecated. [Satisfy your search for knowledge here.](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: The `on` didn't work for me either :/

Comment: You have to use the 3-argument version of `.on()`.

Comment: `.on( "click", "button", function(){});`?

Comment: Right - and you hang the handler on the `<body>` or document, like this: `$('body').on('click', '#btnSubmit', function(e) { ... });` - it basically does the same thing `.live()` did, only better.

Comment: So change my entire Jquery code for the submit button? Can you give me an example?

Comment: When you assign event handlers that way (the 3-argument `.on()`) then they will continue to work even if the DOM is cleared and re-built. It's not clear to me which of your elements is involved with the problem you're having.  I'll add an answer with a general pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change your event handlers such that they use delegation from the `<body>`, then they'll continue to work when the DOM is altered. Thus, for example:

```
$("body").on('click', "#btnSubmit", function (e) {
    alert('test');
    e.preventDefault();

    disablePopup();
});
```

The handler functions really don't have to change (usually). I'm not sure which of the elements on your page are being overwritten by the popup mechanism, but the transformation above can (I'm pretty sure) be made safely for any of your event handlers.

Comment: WOW it worked!!! I should just change to that for any event which is inside UpdatePanel!

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge yes usually I find that it's the simplest and cleanest way to make complicated pages work.

Comment: I never knew that but since I do now... I will use it. Thanks!